# Does Podfile.lock remove the need for putting versions in your Podfile?

Tags: ios, podfile

I'm trying to figure out whether or not I need to specify versions in my Podfile. As far as I can tell, Podfile.lock is doing that for me so I don't see a need to keep the Podfile updated with versions. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what versions exactly? 
if you mean the version of the Pods you're installing then you don't need to, because it'll give you the latest one.
but if you mean the Platform itself - "iOS version" in this case just type the same as the Deployment Target you've in your project.

Comment: The version of the Pods.

Comment: you don't need to specify the version of the pods unless there's a problem or a change and you want an older one, if you want your pods to be the latest version then don't specify the versions.